# Slack Interactive Messages: No POST response from Slack

Tags: node.js, slack-api, ngrok

I'm constructing and sending the message attachment:

```
var zz = {
    "text": "Would you like to play a game??",
    "attachments": [
        {
            "text": "Choose a game to play",
            "fallback": "You are unable to choose a game",
            "callback_id": "wopr_game",
            "color": "#3AA3E3",
            "attachment_type": "default",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "name": "chess",
                    "text": "Chess",
                    "type": "button",
                    "value": "chess"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

web.chat.postMessage(message.source.channel, '', zz);
```

The message with buttons displays fine on Slack, but when I tap a button there's no POST response from Slack to my local ngrok or express route:

`app.post('/slackaction', function(req, res)`

While other messages are posting fine to this route.

I'm seeing this error from Slack after I tap a button:

```
"Oh no, something went wrong. Please try that again"
```

Slack Interactive Messages `request_url` set as:
`https://xxx.ngrok.io/slackaction`

Comment: Try to use GET `app.get('/slackaction', function(req, res)`

Comment: Tried GET but no improvement. Still getting same error "Oh no, something went wrong. Please try that again"

Comment: Is the token you're using for `chat.postMessage` a token you've received as part of the OAuth authorization flow for the same application you've configured the request URL for?

Comment: @TaylorSingletary are you saying that developing/testing responses for Interactive Messages will not work when someone is using a Test Token for chat.postMessage API?

Comment: @hatter123 yes, interactive messages requires using a Slack app for the whole end-to-end process. The messages must originate from the same app that's setup to process the actions activated by those same messages.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to comments from Taylor Singletary for pointing me in the right direction.

The test tokens or a bot token for Custom Integrations can post Interactive Messages but you need an App to handle them.

To fix it you need to add a bot to your app here: https://api.slack.com/apps
and then get the access token for that bot.

You can use the Slack button generator here: https://api.slack.com/docs/slack-button# to get the OAuth URL and paste it on a browser.

Then from your app handle the OAuth flow, store the access token and use that with chat.postMessage.

Then you should receive the POST request when clicking on the message buttons.

Comment: You mean add a bot **user** to your app?